# std:numeric_limits<double>::epsilon definition

Tags: c++, double

`numeric_limits::espilon` returns the difference between 1 and the next double. So, should I understand that the distance between two adjacent doubles is not always the same, for instance between 2 and the next double?

And if yes could I have a piece of explanation ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "density" of floating-point numbers decreases ***a lot*** as you get farther away from zero.

This is because IEEE floating-point is stored essentially as scientific notation, so range is favored over uniform precision. (If it was uniform precision, it would be fixed-point, not floating-point.)

In other words, numbers are stored in the form *Significand * 2<sup>exponent</sup>*, so if the exponent gets large, a small change in the significand produces a large change in the number (and vice-versa).

So no, you can't assume that the difference between 2 and the next double is the same as epsilon; it isn't.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that this is a conscious design choice: it is often useful to have a high precision near zero, while we're more forgiving with larger numbers. So float/double is a nice all-round datatype which is *often* good enough at precise, small numbers and at large, but less precise, ones. It's an attempt at making a simple 32- or 64-bit-wide data type as widely useful as possible. Anyway, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

Doubles are floating point numbers. They consist of a signum, a significand and an exponent.

The higher the exponent, the larger the difference between a double and its successor.

The lower the exponent, the smaller the difference between a double and its successor.